# Gson: skip node level for serialization

Tags: java, json, gson

I have some json which contains fields with custom names, e.g.:

```
{
   "user_id": 123,
   "user_name": "John",
   "field_with_custom_name_1": "value1",
   "field_with_custom_name_2": "value2",
   "field_with_custom_name_3": "value3"
}
```

For describe this json the next model was created:

```
public class UserData {

   @SerializedName("user_id")
   private int userId;

   @SerializedName("user_name")
   private String userName;

   private Map<String, String> customFields;
}
```

But after serialization we have json with the next structure:

```
{
   "user_id": 123,
   "user_name": "John",
   "customFields": {
      "field_with_custom_name_1": "value1",
      "field_with_custom_name_2": "value2",
      "field_with_custom_name_3": "value3"
   }
}
```

Can you suggest how to ignore "customFields" level in the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following annotation to exclude a field from serialization and deserialization:

```
@Expose (serialize = false, deserialize = false)
```

Comment: `Expose` exclude whole node and result will be the next:

{
   "user_id": 123,
   "user_name": "John"
}


But required:

{
   "user_id": 123,
   "user_name": "John",
   "field_with_custom_name_1": "value1",
   "field_with_custom_name_2": "value2",
   "field_with_custom_name_3": "value3"
}

Comment: No, because fields names and number aren`t constant

Comment: @noChangesAdded I mean first you can serialize the object in json and then manipulate the json to flatten any array it contain.